# Is /usr/src directory related to the booting of Linux kernel in any way? If yes, how?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-10.04, boot

Specifically, I was running Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx), and accidentally mounted an empty device (partition) at /usr/src. I forgot to unmount the empty device and on rebooting Ubuntu greets me with a message similar to the following:

> "Ubuntu will now start in low-graphics mode as it can't find the
>   configuration for relevant drivers"

And then it sits idle just like that, with a dark screen (after I click okay on the above dialog box). It also gives me an option to configure the options myself (which I am not comfortable doing).
I am suspecting that this is related to /usr/src being empty as that is the only stupid thing I remember doing. Can somebody explain if this is really the case?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you mounted something on `/usr/src`, on reboot it will get unmounted (as long as you didn't configure `/etc/fstab` to mount it again)

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not. This directory is empty by default but you can have some source trees in it, for example linux kernel source tree. Anyway it is unlikely that some files from that directory are used during the boot process.

Comment: I was following steps given here: http://dinomite.net/2007/setting-up-ubuntu-for-building-kernel-modules/#.T_FRHxceBH5 and that's why /usr/src had  linux source tree (in addition to linux headers that already existed). The space ran out while building kernel and therefore I mounted a new partition at /usr/src, but forgot to copy the original   contents. Next time, I reboot, I see this. Btw, do you have any idea  if I necessarily need to do the kernel build in /usr/src directory (as done in the link)? My guess is no. (Somehow, I can't comment on that blog).